# Fully left aligning text in Excel?

Tags: excel, text-alignment

I feel like there has to be an easy to answer to this, but I haven't found it.

Say in Excel I have 3 cells with text, B1, B2, and B3, each with different font sizes (10, 15, and 30). Text is left-aligned in all cells. When I print, there is some space before the first letter in each cell (and the space is bigger the bigger the font) so that the words do not align.

How do I eliminate this space so that fonts of all sizes will all have zero gaps before the first letter?

Comment: Interesting.  I don't know that you can as I don't see an adjustment for Kerning in Excel.  But if you export it too Word, the starting points of the first letter seem to line up.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's much you can do in this situation. Excel cells have a padding that is relative to the font size, i.e. the padding is greater with bigger fonts.

Excel is not a layout application. Word is a little bit better, but it also defaults to bigger indents with bigger fonts. In the screenshot, Word is on the right.

[image]

If you really need pixel-perfect alignment, you may need to use a layout product.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, kerning cannot be adjusted in Excel.  If you must do this in Excel, you may be able to insert some spaces before the first character, and then differentially format those space characters to get the appearance you want.  In the example below, there are two spaces in front of the first line; one space in front of the 2nd, and a space with a very small font size in front of the third item.

Of course, this will also change the actual contents of the cell.

Doing this in Word or some publishing program may be a better option.

[image]